# Is it possible to configure which folder geddy.js is going to use as 'public'?

Tags: node.js, yeoman, geddy

This is my basic webapp folder structure:

```
-> server
   |-> all geddy.js files (is a REST app)
-> client (angularjs managed with yeoman)
   |-> app
   |-> test
   |-> [...]
```

As I am in development mode I have not yet 'built' my client app into the public folder of the geddy.js app. So is it possible to point the 'public' directory to my 'client/app' directory via a config setting? Or am I totally using the wrong approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by looking in the terminal output. It prints the config object:

```
var config = {
 detailedErrors: true
 , debug: true
 , hostname: null
 , staticFilePath: 'path/to/public'
[..]
```

};

So adding:

```
staticFilePath: 'path/to/public'
```

to the config object makes sense :)